# answer a call from Ktor plugin

Tags: kotlin, plugins, ktor

What I'm trying to do: read a call body in a plugin and if the body contains a particular content, stop further processing of the call and answer immediately.

Here's my code and it does what I need it to do, but it also generates `java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Parent job is Cancelling` under the hood. As I understand it, I need to stop the "normal" pipeline flow in this case, but how to do it?

```kotlin
@KtorDsl
class TestPluginConfig

val TestPlugin: RouteScopedPlugin<TestPluginConfig> = createRouteScopedPlugin(
    "TestPlugin",
    ::TestPluginConfig
) {
    on(ReceiveBytes) { call, body ->
        val bodyBytes = body.readFully()

        if (String(bodyBytes) == "1")
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "You wish")

        ByteReadChannel(bodyBytes)
    }
}

private object ReceiveBytes : Hook<suspend (call: ApplicationCall, body: ByteReadChannel) -> ByteReadChannel> {
    override fun install(
        pipeline: ApplicationCallPipeline,
        handler: suspend (call: ApplicationCall, body: ByteReadChannel) -> ByteReadChannel
    ) {
        pipeline.receivePipeline.intercept(ApplicationReceivePipeline.Before) { body ->
            if (body !is ByteReadChannel) return@intercept
            val newBody = handler(call, body)
            proceedWith(newBody)
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun ByteReadChannel.readFully(): ByteArray {
    var array = ByteArray(0)
    while (!this.isClosedForRead) {
        val packet = this.readRemaining(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE.toLong())
        while (!packet.isEmpty) {
            array += packet.readBytes()
        }
    }
    return array
}
```

Comment: Could you please share a code snippet where the `TestPlugin` is installed and an HTTP request that cause a `CancellationException`?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman turns out it is a bit more complicated.
Is my POST logic there is another async {} block and I do not wait for its completion. It is this block being cancelled with the aforementioned exception.

Here's a gist containing a runnable example https://gist.github.com/agathius/78fe10a285b31f7b59ff01b793233d1f#file-pluginresponse-kt
My whole idea was to AVOID executing that logic and return a cached response.

If you run `curl -i -XPOST http://localhost:8082/123 -d "1"`, you'll see that the block is being executed anyway

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce a `CancellationException` using your code. How do you start the server?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman me neither, I cannot figure out why it is happening in my code. But that's not the point anyway.
If you look at how the POST runs, you'll see that lines 42-45 of the gist are still being executed even though the server ALREADY responded the call in line 65. I'd like to avoid that execution

Comment: You can save a handler's coroutine context in the `Attributes` to cancel it later. Here is the gist with modified code https://gist.github.com/Stexxe/53f0e29e25ba683ba465a3f96f6c1f23

Comment: @AlekseiTirman, hmm. It means that `post<path> {body()}` actually executes BEFORE my plugin hence it will at least start the execution anyway. Definitely not what I've had in mind. Is it possible to intercept pipeline before method body begins its execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this.call.receiveText()` triggers execution of the `ApplicationReceivePipeline`, which is intercepted in the `ReceiveBytes` hook. To avoid executing a route's handler block, you need to place the `receiveText()` call at the beginning of it to cancel the handler's coroutine execution before any of its code is executed. You can save a handler's `coroutineContext` to the `Attributes` of the call to cancel the handler's coroutine in the hook's handler.

```
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.locations.*
import io.ktor.server.locations.post
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.ktor.server.request.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import io.ktor.util.*
import io.ktor.utils.io.*
import io.ktor.utils.io.core.*
import kotlin.text.String
import io.ktor.server.plugins.callid.*
import io.ktor.server.plugins.callloging.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.cancel
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext


@OptIn(KtorExperimentalLocationsAPI::class)
object Paths {
    @Location("/123")
    class Root
}

private val contextKey = AttributeKey<CoroutineContext>("context")

@OptIn(KtorExperimentalLocationsAPI::class)
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8082) {
        install(Locations)
        install(CallLogging)
        install(TestPlugin)

        routing {
            trace {
                application.log.trace(it.buildText())
            }

            post<Paths.Root> {
                call.attributes.put(contextKey, coroutineContext) // Save current coroutine context
                val text = this.call.receiveText()
                // this async logic is being started even though the call is already answered
                // it is much more complicated in my original code, and it's being killed with `java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Parent job is Cancelling`
                async {
                    println("start delay")
                    delay(10000)
                    println("end delay")
                }
                call.respondText(text)
            }
        }

    }.start(wait = true)
}


@KtorDsl
class TestPluginConfig

val TestPlugin: RouteScopedPlugin<TestPluginConfig> = createRouteScopedPlugin(
    "TestPlugin",
    ::TestPluginConfig
) {
    on(ReceiveBytes) { call, body ->
        val bodyBytes = body.readFully()

        if (String(bodyBytes) == "1") {
            call.attributes[contextKey].cancel() // Cancel a route's handler children jobs
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "You wish")
        }

        ByteReadChannel(bodyBytes)
    }
}

private object ReceiveBytes : Hook<suspend (call: ApplicationCall, body: ByteReadChannel) -> ByteReadChannel> {
    override fun install(
        pipeline: ApplicationCallPipeline,
        handler: suspend (call: ApplicationCall, body: ByteReadChannel) -> ByteReadChannel
    ) {
        pipeline.receivePipeline.intercept(ApplicationReceivePipeline.Before) { body ->
            if (body !is ByteReadChannel) return@intercept
            val newBody = handler(call, body)
            proceedWith(newBody)
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun ByteReadChannel.readFully(): ByteArray {
    var array = ByteArray(0)
    while (!this.isClosedForRead) {
        val packet = this.readRemaining(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE.toLong())
        while (!packet.isEmpty) {
            array += packet.readBytes()
        }
    }
    return array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AlekseiTirman, I ended up with a sightly different solution.

The essentials:

1. Custom POST function

```kotlin
val callIsProcessedAttributeKey: AttributeKey<Boolean> = AttributeKey("CallIsProcessedAttrKey")

@KtorExperimentalLocationsAPI
inline fun <reified T : Any, reified Q : Serializable> Route.typedPost(
    noinline handler: suspend PipelineContext<Unit, ApplicationCall>.(Q) -> Unit
): Route =
    post<T> {
        // will start ApplicationReceivePipeline
        val obj = call.receive<Q>()

        val callShouldBeHandled = !Try { call.attributes[callIsProcessedAttributeKey] }
            .getOrElse(false)
        
        // decides if we want to proceed with the request or it is already answered with the plugin
        if (callShouldBeHandled) 
            handler(obj)
    }
```

2. Before answering in the plugin, I set this call attribute to true

```kotlin
   call.attributes.put(callIsProcessedAttributeKey, true)
   call.respond(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "You wish")
```